# NVARCHAR(?) for Email addresses in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, sql-server-2008-r2, nvarchar

For Email addresses, how much space should I give the columns in SQL Server.

I found this definition on Wikipedia:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address
>
> The format of email addresses is local-part@domain where the
> local-part may be up to 64 characters long and the domain name may
> have a maximum of 253 characters - but the maximum 256 characters
> length of a forward or reverse path restricts the entire email address
> to be no more than 254 characters

And this one:

> http://askville.amazon.com/maximum-length-allowed-email-address/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=1166932
>
> So for now, total characters allowed for e-mail address is 64 (local
> part) + 1("@" sign) + 255 (domain part) = 320
>
> It's possible that in the future they'll increase the local-part limit
> to 128 characters. which would make total of 384 characters.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've always used 320 based on your latter calculation. It doesn't cost you anything to allow more*, unless people abuse it and stuff junk in there. It *could* cost you to allow less, as you'll have a frustrating users if they have legitimately longer e-mail addresses and now you'll have to go back and update schema, code, parameters etc. In the system I used to work with (an e-mail service provider), the longest e-mail address I came across naturally was about 120 characters - and it was clear they were just making a long e-mail address for grins.

> * *Not strictly true, since memory grant estimates are based on the assumption that varying-width columns are half-populated, so a wider column storing the same data can have lead to vastly different performance characteristics of certain queries.*

And I've debated whether `NVARCHAR` is necessary for e-mail address. I've yet to come across an e-mail address with Unicode characters - I know the standard supports them, but so many existing systems do not, it would be pretty frustrating if that was your e-mail address.

And while it's true that `NVARCHAR` costs double the space, with SQL Server 2008 R2 you can benefit from Unicode compression, which basically treats all non-Unicode characters in an `NVARCHAR` column as ASCII, so you get those extra bytes back. Of course compression is only available in Enterprise+...

Another way to reduce space requirements is to use a central lookup table for all observed domain names, and store `LocalPart` and `DomainID` with the user, and store each unique domain name only once. Yes this makes for more cumbersome programming, but if you have 80,000 hotmail.com addresses, the cost is 80,0000 x 4 bytes instead of 80,000 x 11 bytes (or less with compression). If storage or I/O is your bottleneck, and not CPU, this is definitely an option worth investigating.

I wrote about this here:

- [Storing E-mail addresses more efficiently in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2657/storing-email-addresses-more-efficiently-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: @tugberk sorry in the notification delay but I wrote about this here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2657/storing-email-addresses-more-efficiently-in-sql-server/

Comment: Just for info : ASP.NET membership provider create database "AspNetUsers" using "nvarchar(256)" for the Email field.

Comment: Another mic drop by Bertrand.

Answer (score 0):

I guess VARCHAR(320) would be the normal limit for an ASCII-based domain name and email address. But won't we start seeing unicode domain names appearing sometime soon?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Maybe NVARCHAR(320) is what we should start using?

Comment: I honestly believe it will be a *long* time before we start seeing broad adoption of Unicode characters in domain names and e-mail addresses. The number of e-mail servers alone that will just barf on them represents some huge momentum against it...

Comment: You are right. If we care about that much on the length, we should do the same for unicode.